# Looping through image pixels is crashing my program

Tags: java, image, performance, swing, image-processing

I started to work into a little image processing software. Currently I just need to set a image to black & white and loop through its pixels and generate a report of a counter, coordinates and color of each pixel (#,x,y,color).

It works fine with tiny images I create just to test, but when I use a real picture, it takes several minutes or even crash my software. My code inside the loop seems to be simple to be crashing.

Any tip on how can I improve it? Thanks in advance!

```
void processImage(BufferedImage image) {
        exportStr = "#,x,y,color"+ newline;     

        Color c = new Color(0);
        int imgW = image.getWidth();
        int imgH = image.getHeight();
        matrix = new int[imgW][imgH]; 

        int currentPx = 1;

        for(int x=0; x < imgW; x++) 
        {
            for(int y=0; y < imgH; y++) 
            {
                c = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y));

                if(c.equals(Color.WHITE))
                { 
                    matrix[x][y] = 1;                   
                }

                String color = matrix[x][y]==1 ? "W" : "B";
                exportStr += formatStringExport(currentPx, x, y, color); // just concatenate values
                currentPx++;
            }
        }

        return img;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `matrix` array? You can export string without this array also.

Comment: @Braj, I'll need that matrix later, althought I'm not using right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably your problem

```
exportStr += formatStringExport(currentPx, x, y, color);
```

Use a `StringBuilder` instead:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(imgW  * imgH * <String size per pixel>);

....

sb.append(formatStringExport(currentPx, x, y, color));
```

Check the [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) documentation for details. Additionally, you could try to reduce the number of objects being created. So for instance replace:

```
c = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y));

String color = matrix[x][y]==1 ? "W" : "B";
```

by ...

```
if(image.getRGB(x, y).equals(...))

sb.append(formatStringExport(currentPx, x, y, (matrix[x][y]==1 ? "W" : "B")));
```

Good luck! :)

Comment: StringBuilder really improved a lot the performance. Thanks!
As `getRGB()` returns int, I used `if(image.getRGB(x, y)==Color.WHITE)`